# Problem with generating non-repetitive random numbers in each row of a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with generating non-repetitive random numbers using Math.random in Java. Numbers should be generated in each row of 2d array (each row is of predefined 15 numbers length). Each row of array should have numbers generated within set: 1 - 49.

So, for example the output should look like:

```
{1,4,5,8,16,21,24,28,32,34,43,45,46,47,48}
{2,5,6,7,8,11,16,19,24,27,34,35,36,45,49}
```

I wrote a function called generateLottos() of type returning: [][], so 2D Array, but I can't get an array of even more like 2 rows with non-repeated numbers, because the program doesn't show anything in console and looks like it runs in an infinite loop.

Function generateLottos() works like this:

```java
public int [][] generateLottos(int[][] arrOfLottos){
    boolean[] numbers = new boolean[MAX_NUM + 1];
    int random;

    for (int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++){
        numbers[i] = false;
    }

    for (int i=0; i< arrOfLottos.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<arrOfLottos[i].length; j++){
            do {
                random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *49 +1);
            }while (numbers[random]);

            arrOfLottos[i][j] = random;
            numbers[random] =true;
        }
        if (i!=0) {
            for (int k=1; k<= MAX_NUM; k++){
                numbers[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return arrOfLottos;
}
```

Boolean array: boolean[] numbers = new boolean[MAX_NUM + 1]; is used to create an array of boolean which each index has value from 1 to MAX_NUM = 49 and is at the start set to false:

```java
boolean[] numbers = new boolean[MAX_NUM + 1];
int random;

for (int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++){
    numbers[i] = false;
}
```

This array of boolean makes sure that the numbers in each row do not repeat. It is nested in for loop with do while instruction to generate random number. Instruction if(i!=0) sets boolean numbers to false for generating next row of non repeated random numbers:

```java
for (int i=0; i< arrOfLottos.length; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<arrOfLottos[i].length; j++){
        do {
            random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *49 +1);
        }while (numbers[random]);

        arrOfLottos[i][j] = random;
        numbers[random] =true;
    }
    if (i!=0) {
        for (int k=1; k<= MAX_NUM; k++){
            numbers[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The code for whole program looks like this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class LottoSorting {

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static final int drawSize = 15; // size of each row of an array

    private static final int MAX_NUM = 49; //Max number possible to generate using rand function

    // Function to get array's number of rows
    public int[][] getLottosArr(){
        System.out.println("Please enter number of draws to generate: ");

        int drawsNum = scanner.nextInt();

        int[][] lottosArr = new int[drawsNum][drawSize];
        scanner.close();

        return lottosArr;
    }

    public int [][] generateLottos(int[][] arrOfLottos){
        boolean[] numbers = new boolean[MAX_NUM + 1];
        int random;

        for (int i=1; i<=MAX_NUM; i++){
            numbers[i] = false;
        }

        for (int i=0; i< arrOfLottos.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<arrOfLottos[i].length; j++){
                do {
                    random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() *49 +1);
                }while (numbers[random]);

                arrOfLottos[i][j] = random;
                numbers[random] =true;
            }
            if (i!=0) {
                for (int k=1; k<= MAX_NUM; k++){
                    numbers[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return arrOfLottos;
    }


    public void printArray(int [][] lottosArr){
        System.out.println("lottos array:");

        for (int i=0; i< lottosArr.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j< lottosArr[i].length; j++){
                if ( j==0){
                    System.out.println("\n Draw nr: " + (i+1));
                }else  {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(lottosArr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class Lotto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LottoSorting lottoSorting = new LottoSorting();

        lottoSorting.printArray(lottoSorting.generateLottos(
                lottoSorting.getLottosArr()
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would create `List<Integer>` containing all lotto numbers. Shuffle them with `Collections` and pick the first 15 for each row